# Group of comments disappear without a "moved to chat" message

Tags: discussion

A few minutes ago a block of comments disspeared from below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15499/12102). When that happens, isn't there usually a residual message that says they've been "moved to chat" or something similar? I'm just curious what happened - are they gone? moved? deleted? I'm not complaining, I'm just trying to understand procedurally what actually happened. Thanks!

Later I saw the "red square message" that linked to this:

[image]

It's dated 3:20PM - is that UTC? Because it's late at night here!

[image]

Oh, now it changed color and shows in my local time. Curiouser and Curiouser!

I've had some weird delays with SX SE tonight, and Captchas are really behaving strangely as well!

Comment: The changing from yellow to white background just means you have read it

Comment: I just felt that with Rory's comments gone, which he removed because he had looked after the matters they mentioned, they looked odd and could be misinterpreted out of context. So, i deleted them rather than risk that. The other things about time... couldn't tell you. If it continues we can check into it.

Comment: @kimholder everything's good, thanks! I just like to understand how this works. I haven't figured out how to chat yet - I pull down a gray arrow and see a "reply to this message" option, but nothing happens when I click it. Some day maybe I'll try to use chat, but I'm an ink-on-paper person and it's just so ephemeral and gimmicky to me.

Comment: Hm. It can be useful, and since you have mentioned other glitches, it would probably be a good idea to check whether this is a technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, comments are not always moved to chat. They can be deleted by moderators at any time for any reason. In this case, Kim removed them because they were obsolete.

By the way, deleted comments are not permanently gone. Moderators have the ability to view these comments and even undelete them, though we can't undelete user-deleted comments.

Comment: OK great, thanks! I added an image to my question - the message just appeared about 2 minutes ago. It's dated 3:20PM - is that UTC?

Comment: Yes, that is UTC. Moderators are not required to leave a message after deleting. Kim just did that to be nice. :)

Comment: OK that's fine! They probably collectively deserved deleting.